# PHP variable variable name containing index

Tags: php

```
$arr[0]=123;
$a="arr[0]";
echo $$a;
```

gives me error

> Notice: Undefined variable: arr[0]

on the last line.

What should I do to make it work?

---

EDIT:

Above is the simplification of what I want to do. If someone wants to know why I want to do this, then here's the explanation:

This is something like what I want to do:

```
if(condition){
    $a=$arr1[0][0];
    $b=$arr1[0][1];
    $c=$arr1[0][2];
}
else{
    $a=$arr2[0];
    $b=$arr2[1];
    $c=$arr2[2];
}
```

I can compact it like this:

```
if(condition)
    $arr=$arr1[0];
else
    $arr=$arr2;
$a=$arr[0];
$a=$arr[1];
$a=$arr[2];
```

But I wanted to try doing this using variable variable:

```
if(condition)
    $arr="$arr1[0]";
else
    $arr="$arr2";
$a={$$arr}[0];
$b={$$arr}[1];
$c={$$arr}[2];
```

Sure, we don't `need` variable variables as we can still code without them. I want to know, for learning PHP, why the code won't work.

Comment: You don't need variable variables

Comment: I need them to compact the code.

Comment: `compact the code` ?? you must be joking right ?

Comment: If you want to compact it, use `echo 123;`.

Comment: I guess you mean that it should be $a = $arr[0] ? and then echo $a ?

Comment: @Gumbo and 5 upvotes, do u really think that I'm doing this just to print 123? I had simplified my question for the sake of readers.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes, but using variable variable.

Comment: @user1444680 see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you said what you’re actually trying to accomplish: Your code doesn’t work because if you look at `$arr1[0][0]`, only `arr` is the variable name; the `[0]` are special accessors for certain types like strings or arrays.

With [variable variables](http://php.net/language.variables.variable) you can only specify the name but not any accessor or other operation:

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable.

Your solution with the additional variable holding the array to access later on would be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: `Now that you said what you’re actually trying to accomplish` my initial code was enough to convey the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[FROM PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second.

Use

```
echo ${$a}[0]; // 123
```

Edit : Based on your edit you can simply have

```
list($a, $b, $c) = (condition) ? $arr1[0] : $arr2;
```

Or

```
$array =  (condition) ? $arr1[0] : $arr2;
$a = $array[0];
$b = $array[1];
$c = $array[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do just won't work - the code `$arr[0]` is referencing a variable called `$arr`, and then applying the array-access operator (`[$key]`) to get the element with key `0`. There is no variable called `$arr[0]`, so you cannot reference it with variable-variables any more than you could the expression `$foo + 1` .

The real question is why you want to do this; variable variables are generally a sign of very messy code, and probably some poor choices of data structure. For instance, if you need to select one of a set of variables based on some input, you probably want a hash, and to look up an item using `$hash[$item]` or similar. If you need something more complex, a `switch` statement can often cover the cases you actually need.

If for some reason you really need to allow an arbitrary expression like `$arr[0]` as input and evaluate it at runtime, you could use `eval()`, but be very very careful of where the input is coming from, as this can be a very easy way of introducing security holes into your code.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you don't need variable variables. To get a `PHP variable variable name containing index` (a key) use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) or [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) or other array parsers. From php's site:

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

You could also use the following (using `$var=` instead of echo):

```
$arr[0]=123;
$arr[1]=456;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "arr[{$key}] = {$value} \r\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
arr[0] = 123
arr[1] = 456
```

But I don't see why you'd do that, since the whole point of the array is not doing that kind of stuff.